.NET Aspire with Aspir8 deploy to kubernetes - Storage Account Connection String
I have a pretty simply .net solution that is using .net aspire.  There is a web project and a service project that use .net orleans.  To support orleans I am using Azure Storage.  I currently have the AppHost setup to use the storage emulator and this works great on my local machine.  When I try to aspirate generate and aspirate deploy to my local kubernetes (rancher) I'm left with a broken app because the connection string is not correct.
// Add the resources which you will use for Orleans clustering and
// grain state storage.
var storage = builder
    .AddAzureStorage("storage")
    .RunAsEmulator();

var clusteringTable = storage.AddTables("clustering");
var grainStorage = storage.AddBlobs("grain-state");

builder.AddOrleans("default")
    .WithClustering(clusteringTable)
    .WithGrainStorage("Default", grainStorage);

This is from my manifest.json file
    "clustering": {
      "type": "value.v0",
      "connectionString": "{storage.outputs.tableEndpoint}"
    },
    "grain-state": {
      "type": "value.v0",
      "connectionString": "{storage.outputs.blobEndpoint}"
    },

The logs after deploy have the following error message
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Connection string doesn't have value for keyword '{storage.outputs.tableEndpoint}'.

It looks like aspir8 is generating a bicep for the storage account which i do not necessarily want to use or at the very least would like it to match what I've already configured.
Ultimately, I think my question here is, how do I get connection strings that are considered secrets inside my app and used for the storage account?  Am I supposed to hardcode it into the manifest.json?

Aspirate doesn't understand azure resources. I believe that's why you are seeing that error.
